# cannot able to encode the excel sheet using jexceapi

Tags: java, jexcelapi

I have to create one excel sheet using JExcel api..I cannt able to encode the excel file and am not able to sure whether the file is encoded or not ?...
pls help

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Locale;

import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.SheetSettings;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.WorkbookSettings;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
import jxl.write.WriteException;

public class Jexcel_test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try
    {       

        WorkbookSettings ws = new WorkbookSettings();
        ws.setLocale(new Locale("en", "EN"));        
        ws.setCharacterSet(0);
        ws.setEncoding("utf-8");
        ws.setDrawingsDisabled(true);
        ws.setGCDisabled(true);

        System.out.println(ws.getCharacterSet());
        System.out.println(ws.getArrayGrowSize());
        System.out.println(ws.getExcelDisplayLanguage());
        System.out.println(ws.getExcelRegionalSettings());


        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter filename  :");
        File filename= new File("f:/"+br.readLine()+".xls"); 

        Workbook wb1=Workbook.getWorkbook(filename, ws);

        Sheet s  = wb1.getSheet(0);

       SheetSettings settings = s.getSettings();
        settings.setDefaultRowHeight(500);
        if(!settings.isProtected())
        {               
            settings.setPassword("test");               
        }   
        settings.setFitToPages(true);   

        System.out.println(s.getName());


        for (int row = 1; row < s.getRows(); row++) {
            String val = s.getCell(0, row).getContents().trim();
            System.out.println(val);
        }


        wb1.close();


        System.out.println("Enter new filename  :");
        File filename1= new File("f:/"+br.readLine()+".xls"); 
        WritableWorkbook wb2 = Workbook.createWorkbook(filename1, ws);
        WritableSheet sheet = wb2.createSheet("mysheet",0); 

        SheetSettings settings1 = sheet.getSettings();
        settings1.setDefaultRowHeight(500);
        settings1.setProtected(true);
        settings1.setPassword("test");
        settings1.setFitToPages(true);  
        System.out.println("Workbook  "+filename1+"  created");

        wb2.write();
        wb2.close();

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch (BiffException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (WriteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First write some non-ascii data in one of the column and then read the same.. you'll get the answer.